# How to correctly use compose to combine HOCs that encapsulate protected routes in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm apparently not grasping the concept of `compose` through `Redux` as I can't get it working as expected.

I currently have two nested HOCs around one of my protected routes: one makes sure the user is verified before navigating to the protected route and the other is just a timer that kicks them out of the protected route if they are idle.

I want to leverage `compose` so that I can clean up my code and not nest my protected routes in HOCs.

This is what I currently have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routerMiddleware, ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

// Render on every route
import App from './components/app';

// Route specific
import Signin from './containers/authentication/signin';
import Signout from './containers/authentication/signout';
import Home from './components/home';

// HoC to wrap protected routes in
import RequireAuth from './helpers/require_auth';
import Timer from './helpers/timer';

// Reducers 
import rootReducer from './reducers';

// SCSS for the project
import styles from '../assets/scss/main.scss';

const history = createHistory();

const initialState = {};
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension

    if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
        enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
    }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers);
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <App />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/home' component={LeftSite(RequireAuth(Home))} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signout' component={Signout} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signin' component={Signin} />
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Signin} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

What I have tried is modifying like so:

```
const composedEnhancers = compose(
                            applyMiddleware(...middleware),
                            ...enhancers
                        );

const protectedRoutes = compose(
                            applyMiddleware(RequireAuth, LeftSite)                            
                        );

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers, protectedRoutes);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <App />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/home' component={protectedRoutes(Home)} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signout' component={Signout} />
                    <Route exact path='/auth/signin' component={Signin} />
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Signin} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

This just results in `Cannot call a class as a function`. Here is one of the HOCs as they both have similar structure:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { authRequired } from '../actions/authentication';

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
    class AuthenticationRequired extends Component {

        // Check if the user has a token when protected route component is about to mount
        // Route them to / if they do not
        componentWillMount() {
            if (!sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
                this.props.authRequired();
            }
        }

        // If the component will be updated then also check if user is authorized
        componentWillUpdate() {
            if (!sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
                this.props.authRequired();
            }
        }

        // Render the component if passing these checks
        render() {
            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }

    // Conenct to the authRequired action
    return connect( null, { authRequired })(AuthenticationRequired);
}
```

I have tried several variations with varying errors. I wasn't going to post them all. What I have here seems like it might be closer to the correct answer... maybe?

I did read through the documentation which I didn't find helpful in my case:

https://paulkogel.gitbooks.io/redux-docs/content/docs/api/compose.html

So my questions are:

How should I structure the `compose`?

How should do I call it on just my protected routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the docs say, `compose` actually does something very simple, conceptually:

> [All compose does is let you write deeply nested function transformations without the rightward drift of the code. Don’t give it too much credit!](https://paulkogel.gitbooks.io/redux-docs/content/docs/api/compose.html)

So let's say you have three very simple functions like this:

```js
const capitalize = str => str.toUpperCase();
const takeFirstChar = str => str[0];
const prependHello = str => 'hello' + str;
```

If you wanted to use all three in a row, without using `compose`, it would become nested calls like this:

```js
const originalValue = 'test';
console.log(  capitalize(takeFirstChar(prependHello(originalValue))))
// prints  'H' 
// (the first letter from the appended 'hello', capitalized)
```

See how the first function to be called (`prependHello`) is all the way to the right? That's what was meant with "the rightward drift of the code".

But with `compose` we can, instead, write it like this:

```js
// NOTE the order of the arguments!
// The bottom one is applied first, then middle one, then the top one
const prependHelloAndTakeFirstCharToUpper = compose(
  capitalize,
  takeFirstChar,
  prependHello
);

console.log( prependHelloAndTakeFirstCharToUpper(originalValue)   )
// still prints 'H'
```

It's not clear how you where using your HOC's before when they worked, but if you didn't involve things like `applyMiddleWare` before then that probably shouldn't be there now either.

My guess, without knowing more about your code, is that it should work to do something like this:

```js
const protectedRoutes = compose(RequireAuth, LeftSite);

// further down
<Route exact path='/home' component={protectedRoutes(Home)} />
```

And I think you can remove your `protectedRoutes` from your arguments to `createStore`.

Comment: Yea, I was giving it way too much credit and over complicating it. I took it out of `createStore` and it is working as expected now. Thanks!